# Play 1.2.5 admin module shows access denied

Tags: playframework

Here's my code:

#### 1. Application does nothing but some log works.

```
public class Application extends CRUD {

}
```

#### 2. User is the model I want to edit, so I have a Users as Controller:

```
public class Users extends Application {

}
```

#### 3. route:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Import CRUD routes
*      /admin                                   module:crud

# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

Then I follow `localhost:9000/admin`, it shows 404 can't find page :

```
These routes have been tried, in this order :

GET       /@documentation/cheatsheet/{category}             PlayDocumentation.cheatSheet
GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/files/{name}     PlayDocumentation.file
GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/images/{name}    PlayDocumentation.image
GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/{id}             PlayDocumentation.page
GET       /@documentation/files/{name}                      PlayDocumentation.file
GET       /@documentation/images/{name}                     PlayDocumentation.image
GET       /@documentation/{id}                              PlayDocumentation.page
GET       /@documentation/?                                 PlayDocumentation.index
GET       /                                                 Application.index
GET       /favicon.ico                                      404
GET       /public/                                          staticDir:public
GET       /admin/                                           CRUD.index
*         /{controller}/{action}                            {controller}.{action}
```

Then I add a slug `localhost:9000/admin/`:

It turns out access denied !

How do I deal with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the @With annotation instead of extending Application:

```
@With(Application.class)
@CRUD.For(User.class)
public class Users extends CRUD {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The crud controller needs to be named after an entity of your's e.g. if it should administrate  an entity named User it needs to be named Users. Alternatively it can have a @CRUD.For annotation which specifies the entity it should administrate. Since your controller neither matches the naming convention nor has a @CRUD.For annotation, Play is going to have issues with that.

Also your extends classes look wrong. If you say that your model is named "Users" it should extend "Model" and not "Application".  So e.g. if your model is named Users, it should look like this.

```
public class Users extends Model {

... 

}

@CRUD.For(Users.class)
public class UserAdmin extends CRUD {

}
```

On a related note, I would call the Users model User instead, since it represents a single user.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, Users is my controller for User model.

Comment: Your problem probably came from Application extends CRUD.
What methods exists in class Application ? Have you try to remove Application extends CRUD and just do Users extends CRUD ?

Comment: I also experimented some trouble with the word 'User'. Try to rename it (MyUser for ex).